# Show that $\alpha(a) = h$ if and only if $a = gk$ for some $k \in \text{ker} (\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

> Let $\alpha : G → H$ be a homomorphism, and suppose that $\alpha (g) = h$. For any
> $a \in G$, show that $\alpha(a) = h$ if and only if $a = gk$ for some $k \in \text{ker} (\alpha)$.

**My attempt:** Suppose that $a=gk, k \in \text{ker} (\alpha)$. Then

$\alpha(a) =\alpha(gk) = \alpha(g) \alpha(k) =\alpha(g) e=\alpha(g) =h$

Conversely, suppose that $\alpha$ is a homomorphism. If $\alpha(a) =\alpha(g) $, then $\alpha(a)(\alpha(g)) ^{-1} =e$. So

$h=\alpha(a) =\alpha(g)\alpha(a)( \alpha(g)) ^{-1}$

Let $k=ag^{-1}$ then

$h=\alpha(a) =\alpha(gk) $.

Thus $a=gk, k\in  \text{ker} (\alpha)$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine.

You could improve it by making it a little clearer how you conclude that $k\in\ker(\alpha)$.